# Power Automate: How are the actions billed when having multiple owners?

Tags: flow, power-automate, licensing

This is not quite a genuine SharePoint related topic, but I don't know where else to ask it.

My license is rather limited in API-actions per day. However, it is a per user license which limits API actions.

I'm sharing most of my flows among two or three people to ensure that problems can be fixed, when I'm not available. Sharing means that all people you are sharing the flow with are owners then.

Who will be billed the API actions when such a flow is executed?

Comment: you can ask Power Automate licensing related question at (you will get answers more quickly there): https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/bd-p/MPAForum

Comment: I can't ask there, because my company is blocking me from signing in there.